# Prevent removal of busy kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

I have a simple kernel module that creates a character devices and does nothing with it.

I wrote this user-space program that tests the character device.

```
int main()
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("/dev/ebbchar", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        err(1, "open");

    sleep(10);

    ret = close(fd);
    if (ret < 0)
        err(1, "close");
}
```

The program exits after 10 seconds.

But if in the meantime I remove the module with rmmod or modprobe, then after 10 seconds the program segfaults or hangs, and there is a kernel oops.

How can I cause rmmod to fail, or is there a method to safely remove a module?

Could my module, in its __exit function, close the file descriptor?

I assume that the crash is caused by the `close()` function which indirectly calls the `release` callback in the characters file operations, with that `release` function not existing anymore because the module was removed.

The source of the kernel module can be found [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/) (search for *Listing 2*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC you need to set `.owner = THIS_MODULE` in the file operations structure so that the module's reference count gets handled correctly.

Comment: Thank you, now rmmod refuses to unload the module.

Comment: @Bilow, you mean if you try to unload it while file is opened? This is true behaviour of such modules, there is no error.